# What does the lady in this video say?

Tags: translation, audio

I am watching a small advertising video for chinese radio station (here it is https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fL6hj3ocYZM), and cannot quite catch what the lady is saying from 00:12 to "96.3好歌好FM". Can someone please help me with this one?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

She says:

> 又是全新的一天，963好歌好FM。你好吗？
> <sub>Yòu shì quánxīn de yītiān, 963 hǎo gē hǎo FM. Nǐ hǎo ma?</sub>

It's something like:

> It's another totally new day, 963 good songs, good FM.  How are you?

Comment: I would describe it as "How are you?" instead of "Are you good?"

Comment: Sure, why not?  (I also got rid of the "again" which seems redundant.)